# To load a random picture on "page-load"

Tags: jquery

I´m trying to load a random picture on page-load with JQuery cycle plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade', 
        random:  1 
    });
});
```

Any easy way to do that?

Comment: this is the easiest way. what else you want as "easy" ?

Comment: Randomness is impossible in our universe. Nothing is random, everything can be traced back.

Comment: And what you have doesn't work... because?

Comment: I want the picture to chage randomly when page load (on click?).When the user click the btn...

Comment: where's your code for the button? It's hard to guess, we don't read minds. Please put up an example here or even better to http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @wpdesign Please update the question since the question doesn't mention anything about loading a picture with a button click.  Also, the cycle plugin is used to rotate photos, if you are only trying to load 1 random photo you may want to ask how to do that and leave off the cycle plugin reference.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle for loading 1 random photo on page load.  It doesn't use the cycle plugin.   http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/Qw7L4/

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, please select it as the answer by clicking the green arrow or provide more feedback.

Answer (score 1):

A plugin isn't needed to load a random image.  To load a random image out of a set you can put all your images inside some container (or you could add a class to them whatever you want) and then randomly choose one to show.

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/upload/2012/04/why_should_there_be_dark_matte/AS17-148-22727_lrg-thumb-500x500-74032.jpeg" />
  <img src="http://weblogs.marylandweather.com/4526619322_1912218db8.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.silverstar-academy.com/Blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/03-14-12N  00184967.jpg" />     
  <img src="http://cdn.the2012scenario.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/sunspot-500x500.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #slideshow {width:500px;height:500px;overflow:hidden}
 #slideshow img {display:none}
```

JS/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#slideshow img').length);
  $('#slideshow img').eq(rand).show();​
  // if you just want to use a class you could do this but is prob better to put them in a container
  // $('img.random').eq(rand).show();
  // var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('img.random').length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery,

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#slideshow img').length);
$("#slideshow img:eq("+rand+")").show();
```

Doing `.eq(rand).show();`​ doesn't work.

Comment: Could you explain why `.eq(rand).show()` doesn't work? Also, are you sure this works with jQuery cycle plugin per the asker's question?